# kubeadm + calico 3.6 singlenode notready forever

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, calico

I am using Ubuntu bionic (18.04) with latest version of kubeadm on Ubuntu's repositories (1.13.4) and calico 3.6, following their documentation for "Installing with the Kubernetes API datastore—50 nodes or less" (https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.6/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/calico).

It was started with:

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
```

But when I apply calico.yaml my node gets stuck with the condition:

> Conditions:   Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime
>   LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
>   ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------   MemoryPressure   False   Mon, 15 Apr 2019 20:24:43 -0300   Mon, 15 Apr
>   2019 20:21:20 -0300   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has
>   sufficient memory available   DiskPressure     False   Mon, 15 Apr
>   2019 20:24:43 -0300   Mon, 15 Apr 2019 20:21:20 -0300
>   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
>   PIDPressure      False   Mon, 15 Apr 2019 20:24:43 -0300   Mon, 15 Apr
>   2019 20:21:20 -0300   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has
>   sufficient PID available   Ready            False   Mon, 15 Apr 2019
>   20:24:43 -0300   Mon, 15 Apr 2019 20:21:20 -0300   KubeletNotReady
>   runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false
>   reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not
>   ready: cni config uninitialized

When I see the system pods (`kubectl get pods -n kube-system`) I get:

```
NAME                                       READY   STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-55df754b5d-zsttg   0/1     Pending    0          34s
calico-node-5n6p2                          0/1     Init:0/2   0          35s
coredns-86c58d9df4-jw7wk                   0/1     Pending    0          99s
coredns-86c58d9df4-sztxw                   0/1     Pending    0          99s
etcd-cherokee                              1/1     Running    0          36s
kube-apiserver-cherokee                    1/1     Running    0          46s
kube-controller-manager-cherokee           1/1     Running    0          59s
kube-proxy-22xwj                           1/1     Running    0          99s
kube-scheduler-cherokee                    1/1     Running    0          44s
```

May this be a bug or there is something missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the taint on the master node, `kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-`.

Reference here, https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#control-plane-node-isolation